# Need basic step by step instructions to get Flexpaper on to clients website

Tags: macos, pdf, uploading, flexpaper

Greetings o knowledgeable ones,

I may have bitten off more than I can chew and this is the reason why I'm here!

I'm a beginner/intermediate front end coder and I have a client who has asked me to use Flexpaper to view their PDF catalogues on their website.
I know little about PHP and server side stuff (hell, I barely know front end code) and for the life of me I cant find a step by step instruction on how to upload the viewer and the PDFs on to the website/server.
I've read a couple of answers on the website that give me a glimpse into what I need to do but they seem to fall short of a complete answer.

I tried to using the 'Server Publishing' option in my local machine (using MAMP) but got stuck half way through when permissions where denied. Then found an answer eluding to the possibility of publishing to the web using the 'FlexPaper Desktop Publisher Zine' So I downloaded that and published a PDF and now I have a folder that was created on my machine but I'm a little lost from as to what to do next?

**Some specific questions I have:**

- Do I upload the whole folder to the server and if I do what is the
  code I have to include on a web page to access this Flexpaper PDF?
- Do I need to upload any other applications/helper files to make the
  viewer work on the website?
- I have multiple PDFs(approx 15) I need to upload - is using the
  'Desktop Publisher' to create each PDF the best way to do this? Or
  should I use the 'Server Publishing' solution?
- Why have I charged my client so little for so much work!?

*Flexpaper seems like a great option for viewing PDFs online but it seems to be lacking in a beginning-to-end process of how to implement it onto websites. Unless I am missing something....*

I am not a smart man.

Thanks and peace

Comment: Jay – this isn't a super recent question, maybe you've already figured it out. I could help you out. There's are options to know- eg do you want: single PDF file; PDF split to single page PDFs; PDF to SWF; PDF to PNG –– that's one variable. There are performance considerations in that decision. Personally, I've found that Flexpaper provides decent performance only with PNG mode (although I don't know that I have tried SWF mode), unless it's an extremely small PDF.  Let me know if you are still working on this, I may be able to help.

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your reply. I've actually worked out how to access and display on the web. I had to change the read and write access on few folders. My steps where, 1.) upload folder(produced from desktop publisher) and all contents to server. 2.) change permissions on folder to 777(read and write). 3.) Because i was uploading more than one PDF I then added a folder, for each separate PDF published, to the 'docs' folder. 4.) I then duplicated and changed the 'index.html' to reflect the path changes for each PDF.   Not sure if what I've done is the best way but it was the easiest.

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working –– but those 777 file permissions sound like they could be risky if this folder is accessible on the web? You might want to look into 644, or 755 as safer possibilities? 777 means the world can read write and execute on that folder.